# Godaddy with Open XML SDK

Tags: openxml-sdk, asp.net-development-serv

I am trying to load the Open XML SDK library in my webpage on Godaddy.

I am not able to load the dll properly.

I asked the technical support, but all they said is create a folder in their IIS setting and something about "ASP.NET application DLLs" which I don't get.

I think this library should be ok since it just manipulates XML files.

The error I'm getting is:

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DocumentFormat' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the error by using the tick box "Create Application Root".

Note that the application created using the IIS manager on GoDaddy should be the same name as the application created on GoDaddy using the FTP.

This was answered using GoDaddy support.

Answer (score 1):

When you download the Open XML SDK 2.0 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124), it will give you a dll that you will need to include in order to use the `DocumentFormat` namespace.  The specific dll is called `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` and you should copy that dll into the folders the support person told you to create.  You will also need to reference that dll in your project in order to use it. Once you do that the specific error message you are seeing will go away.

Comment: 1 - I created a folder using the steps he provided, but i do not know where that folder is.
2 - How do i reference the dll?

I placed the dll in the bin directory and it works fine locally

Comment: @AhmadHajou - The technical people at godaddy should be the ones to answer that question.

Comment: It turn out there was an option in the folder that I created I needed to check the called "Create Application Root".

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have seen that error is when you are trying to install .MSI files on shared hosting. To have access to that ability, you will need a virtual dedicated (http://x.co/b7Si) or dedicated server (http://x.co/b7Sk).